# Add and update flags based on dates

Tags: sas

I have the following data set:

> ```
>         ID         Start         Stop        
>        001       01JAN2013     31JAN2013             
>        001       01FEB2013     31DEC2013           
>        002       01MAR2013     31DC2013              
>        003       01JAN2013     31DEC2013
> ```

I need the following output:

> ```
>    ID         Start         Stop        Start_flag     End_flag
>   001       01JAN2013     31JAN2013         1             2
>   001       01FEB2013     31DEC2013         2             3
>   002       01MAR2013     31DC2013          1             2
>   003       01JAN2013     31DEC2013         1             2
> ```

In other words I need to add a flag for the start and end with the exception that for consecutive periods the end flag of the previous period will become the start flag of the subsequent period and the remaining end flag will be increased by 1.

Can anyone help me please?

Thnk you in advance

Comment: You don't really have enough test data there.  The only ID with multiple observations is one where there is no gap between the intervals.  What do you want when an ID has a gap in the dates?  Also is it possible for the intervals to actually overlap?  If so can they overlap by more than just the middle date?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I did create groups for intervals in a previous post that would illustrate which sets of records were consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LAG()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/n0l66p5oqex1f2n1quuopdvtcjqb.htm) function

```
proc sort data=have; by id start; run;

data want(drop=lag_stop);
    set have;
    by id start notsorted;

    lag_stop = lag(stop);
    if first.id then do;
        start_flag=1;
        end_flag=start_flag+1;
    end;

    else if lag_stop+1 = start then do;
        start_flag+1;
        end_flag+1;
    end;
run;
```

```
want

id    start      stop   start_flag   end_flag
001 01JAN2013 31JAN2013     1           2
001 01FEB2013 31DEC2013     2           3
002 01MAR2013 31DEC2013     1           2
003 01JAN2013 31DEC2013     1           2
```